# Android stop gps search location

Tags: android, gps

How can stop gps search location when I use GPSTracker as Service [image]

Knowing when I get out of the application I do the following:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
```

But gps still search how disable it...

thanks in advance...

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
```

This should stop requesting updates, maybe you have added another listeners except `GPSTracker.this`. Or maybe some other applications are using gps.

Note that gps are active when gps icon (in notifications bar) is animating.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **LocationClient** (by using *Google Play Services* for Location) then you have to call:

```
mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(YourActivity.this);
```

See this link for more information about using Google Play Services for Location getting: https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html